# Style tikz matrix borders

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I am using tikz to position some nodes easily. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[%
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=1ex,column sep=1em,
        nodes=draw,
        column 1/.style={nodes={circle}},
        column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=2em}}
    ]{%
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        e & f \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This gives

[image: no_border]

My attempt would by to add `draw,rounded corners` to the optional arguments of `\matrix`, but that ends up like so:

[image: with_border]

The `rounded corners` option seems to be applied to all nodes in the matrix as well.
I found `matrix.skeleton`, which has `style contour` that looks like it *might* help me, but just setting `style contour={draw,rounded corners}` does not fit the elements in the matrix as nicely as it draws the smallest bounding box possible and I couldn’t add inner padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `sharp corners` to option list passed to `nodes={<options>}`.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[%
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=1ex,column sep=1em,
        nodes={draw,sharp corners},
        column 1/.style={nodes={circle}},
        column 2/.style={nodes={rectangle,minimum width=2em}},
        draw,rounded corners
    ]{%
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        e & f \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe I didn’t think of that. Thank you. This still feels like a bit of a hack though, but it may just be due to my inexperience with tikz.